# How do I calculate rotation and linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an assignment that is:

Let $T:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ be the linear map which defines by conterclockwise rotation around origo with the angle $\pi/4$. Determine T:s matrix in the standard basis.

There been a while since I did linear algebra at all, so I am feeling quite lost here...

Is $R^2$ a 2x2 matrix? And if it is, is the coordinates for each vector in this matrix written  diagonal or horizontal?

Is this the standard basis: $\pmatrix{1&0 \\0&1} $?

My guess is that I should modify each element in the matrix above with $\pi/4$, am I right? How do I proceed from that?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of the rotation with angle $\theta$  in the standard basis is

$$R_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is this something that I just should know or is it obvious in some way?